# SSIS ETL execute MySQL Stored procedure on Destination Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, business-intelligence

I am working on an SSIS ETL and I wanna know if there is a possibility to execute a MySQL Stored Procedure.

**Here is what I want to do :** From an SQL Server Database, I want to get Information by an ETL (SSIS) and send them to a MySQL Database (by a stored procedure)

**Here is what I have done so far :** I get my data from SQL Server Database and tranform them.

**Here where I am stuck :** I don't know how to execute an existing stored procedure on the MySQL Server Database (my destination)
Here is my ETL (DATA FLOW) diagram :[image]

I also add an OLEDB provider on the server and add my destination source (MySQL Database) but I don't know what I need to do in my ETL to execute the stored procedure.

I can provide more information if necessary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My first thought is the OLEDB Command transformation, but I don't know if it works with MySQL or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you mean that you want to execute a stored procedure by passing in every row in memory in SSIS that enters through your multicast. If that is the case, that may be possible with SSIS, but I have never done it.

why not just send the rows to two separate tables in MySQL from the multicast, then go back to the control flow tab and add two execute sql tasks, one for each stored procedure. Change each stored procedure to run on the tables instead of individual rows.

You would probably get a performance boost as well from switching to a set based operation instead of row by row.